# How to force checking of radiobutton before filling any input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a data entry form with jquery script to insert data into mysql database
In the form, I want user to check one of the radio buttons first before entering any value in the input box tldno. I tried checking the status of radio button by binding blur event to tldno. But the problem is , once the blur event is triggered, it is not allowing clicking of the radio button. How to implement it effectively.

This is the form

```
<form id="personnel_data">
<fieldset >
<legend> Personnel Data</legend>

<label for "kgsunit">Select KGS Unit </label><input name="unit" type="radio" value="1" <?php if($user_unit=='1'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?>/> 1&amp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="unit" type="radio" value="3"  <?php if($user_unit=='3'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?> /> 3&amp;4&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="unit" type="radio" value="6"  <?php if($user_unit=='6'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?> /> 5&amp;6<br/>
<label for "tld">TLD No. </label>
 <input type="text" id="tldno" name="tldno" size="25" maxlength="25" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/><br/>

 <label for "fname">Full Name</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size=30 maxlength=30onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keycode=9;"/><br/>

 <label for "dob">Date of Birth</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"  /><input type="hidden" id="stddate" name="stddate" value="<?php echo $dateus; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>"/><br/>

 <label for "cat"> Category</label><input name="cat" type="radio" value="R"  />
        Regular
        <input type="radio" name="cat" value="C" checked="checked"/>Casual<br/>
 <div id="emp"><br/><label for "ccno">CC No.</label><input type="text" name="ccno" id="ccno" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/><br/>
 <label for "empno">Employee No.</label><input type="text" name="empno"  id="empno" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/></div><br/>
 <label for "section">Section</label><select name="section" id="section">
          <?php 
    $db=mysql_select_db($database_met,$met) or die("could not connect");
$secsql= "SELECT *
           FROM sections
           ORDER BY secname; 
             ";
  $result_sec=@mysql_query($secsql) or die(mysql_error());
                            echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select Section</option>';
                            while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result_sec))
                                    { echo($row2['secname']);
                                    echo"<option>".$row2['secname']."</option>";}



    ?>
        </select>
    <label for "height"> Height in cm</label><input type="text" name="height" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/></td>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add record" /></td>


</form>
```

jquery part

```
jQuery("#tldno").blur(function(){




    var rep_sel=jQuery("[name='unit']:checked").val();
    if(typeof rep_sel === "undefined"){

        alert ('Please Select a Unit First');
        jQuery("#tldno").val("");
        jQuery('#tldno').focus();


    }
    else{
    var name = rep_sel.concat(jQuery("#tldno").val());

    jQuery.post("tld_search_hpu.php", {"name":name},  function(data) { 

        if (data.msg=="Y"){ 
            alert("Data Exists"); 
            jQuery('#submit').hide();
            jQuery('#tldno').focus();
        } 

        else {
            jQuery('#submit').show();  
        }
    });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want, but you can try this:

```
$(function(){
    var status=false;
    $('#tldno').focus(function(){
        if($('#personnel_data input[name="unit"]:checked').length == 0){
            $('#personnel_data input[name="unit"]').eq(0).focus();
            status = false;
        }else{
            status=true;
        }
    });

    $('#tldno').keyup(function(){
        if(status){
            console.log('do your ajax here')
        }
    })


});
```